# Queue implementation is losing track of head node

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a queue add function implemented

```
void queue::add(myObj info)
{
    node* node = new node;

    node->info = &info; //<---suspect
    node->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL){
        head = node;
    }
    else{
        tail->next = node;
    }
    tail = node;
    count++;

}
```

Every time this gets visited the head node's data points to whatever I'm passing in. I realize there is a template for this but I am trying to build one, because I obviously need practice.

I am trying to keep all the pointers pointed to the original objects. I wanted to pass in the object and point to the refrence.

The node is a struct with `myObj * info` and `node * next`

Comment: Problem 1: You pass `info` by value, so by the time the function call ends, your `info` is deleted!! And your `node->info` is dangling!

Comment: @user007 that was absolutely it. Whats left of my hair thanks you.

Comment: Umm.. Well, I don't exactly know what that meant. But I assume its solved!

Answer (score 1):

`info` is a parameter of your function, that is passed by value.  In this case, `&info` is the address of the parameter, and not of the original data.

This is undefined behaviour and can only give weird results.

One possible solution would be:

```
void queue::add(myObj& info)  // pass by reference
{
    ... // unchanged code
}
```

In this case, `&info` would refer to the address of the original object.